C++- error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
I'm getting
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
362 | #define min(a,b)   (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
    |                    ^

in this piece of code:
/* min and max macros */
#ifndef NOMINMAX
#ifndef max
#define max(a,b)   (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b)) 
#endif
#ifndef min
#define min(a,b)   (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))  
#endif
#endif  /* NOMINMAX */

I'm on Linux  22 and trying to compile simple Windows app with Wine. It's includes windows.h from wine/include where the error occurs.
The gcc version is 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04).

"in this piece of code:" - you mean that you copy-pasted part of windows.h as your production code? Can you show your real code that causes the problem? Did you apply the NOMINMAX fix, like mentioned in many similar questions ?

@pptaszni Yes, it solves it. I was looking at questions that had error in title not the windows.h as i thought it was too specific. Question is duplicate.
